# How to set the code 128-C in Jasper Report using Barcode4j?

Tags: jasper-reports, barcode4j

Good Day!

Anyone know how to set the Code 128-C in Jasper Report using Barcode4j?

I believed that the default is set to ABC. I saw in this link http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/2.1/symbol-code128.html and this is the default configuration.

Where I can find this code to edit it, or is the other way that I can configure using Jasper Report?

Btw, I'm using iReport 3.6.7 for a reason.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the same problem but after some google i just added some string in C-DATA ...

Just try this code .

```
<componentElement>
    <reportElement uuid="a2f054f0-4729-4843-af96-c34c9a84b84c" x="1" y="50" width="93" height="41"/>
    <jr:Code128 textPosition="bottom">
        <jr:codeExpression>
            <![CDATA["TESTING 123"]]>
        </jr:codeExpression>
    </jr:Code128>
</componentElement>
```

or you can go through this(http://www.keepdynamic.com/barcoding/barcode-ireport.shtml) link...

Hope it Helps !!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I switched to Barbeque.